# Forcing copy on assignment

Tags: r, copy

I have an R6 object, say "foo", from which I need to extract a few slot values before calling foreach with doFuture backend.  The only thing relevant in this context is that doFuture automatically detects what needs to be exported and exports it.  Foo is a very large object, so I only want a few field values without exporting the whole object:

`myList = list(x = foo$x, y = foo$y)`.

However, probably because of delayed copy, the entire "foo" object is exported, as well as myList.  How do I force a copy at the time of assignment to myList to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like duplicate() in the rlang package does it!